# Apollo graphql subscribeToMore doesn't receive the new subscriptionData

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

Why the `subscriptionData` inside the `updateQuery` parameter is receiving the query data and not the data from the subscription ?

The query:

```
const {
    data,
    error: homePageError,
    loading: homePageLoading,
    refetch: refetchRaw,
    subscribeToMore,
  } = useHomePageQuery({
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    skip: !currentAccountId || screen !== "HOME",
    variables: {
      accountId: currentAccountId ?? "none",
    },
  });
```

the subscription:

```
useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToMore({
      document: gql`
        subscription HomePageRemoteChargeCreated($userId: ID!) {
          remoteChargeCreated(userId: $userId) {
            remoteCharge {
              id
              station {
                id
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
        const createdRemoteCharge = subscriptionData.data.remoteChargeCreated;

        return {
          me: {
            ...prev.me,
            account: {
              ...prev.me?.account,
              accountUser: {
                ...prev.me?.account?.accountUser,
                currentRemoteCharge: {
                  id: createdRemoteCharge?.id,

                  station: { ...createdRemoteCharge.station },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        };
      },
      variables: {
        userId: currentUserId,
      },
    });
  }, [client, currentAccountId, currentUserId, subscribeToMore]);
```

What I get in `subscriptionData` type (I should received the content declared inside of the subscription):

```
(parameter) subscriptionData: {
    data: HomePageQuery;
}
```

I'm using `"@apollo/client": "3.7.1"` and `"react": "18.2.0",`

Is anyone having a clue on this ?